# Save Lokijs DB in Electron

Tags: electron, lokijs, asar

there is some way from inside the "main.js" electron to save a file out of the asar?
I'm fighting with this command to point the way out of the write-only area but I can not do it.
It would be nice that the path was inside `/my-project/resources/` and would work even without the electron-package.

```
let configFilePath = `${__dirname}/../config.json`
db = new loki(configFilePath)
if(fs.existsSync(configFilePath))
    db.loadDatabase()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attempting to write a file within the application installation directory is a bad idea, often the user will not have the permission to do so. Instead you should write files to the location returned by [`app.getPath('userData')`](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#appgetpathname).